# BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;

Tags: java

When you do something like this

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
```

why does bigDecimal **become a new object**?

Comment: Compare the two with == (`bigDecimal and `BigDecimal.ONE`) - it'll return true, meaning the underlying object is the same.

Comment: why do you believe it does.

Answer (score 8):

In this case, the variable (or field) `bigDecimal` doesn't become a new object. It is only a reference to the object which is referenced by the existing static field `java.math.BigDecimal.ONE`.

The object itself (the one that represents `1`) is created only once: when the class `BigDecimal` is loaded. For Java 7, this is done using `new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE,          1, 0, 1)`.

The assignment you did is better than creating a new object yourself using `= new BigDecimal(...)`, because the existing object is re-used.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it, if you then bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ONE); then bigDecimal would be = 2

Comment: `BigDecimal` is immutable, so when you assign `bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ONE)` a new object is returned from the `add` method (i.e. `add` does not modify the reference to `BigDecimal.ONE`).

Comment: More accurately, it's a reference to the same object that is referenced by the existing static field `BigDecimal.ONE`. (That is, it's a reference to an object, not to a field.)

Answer (score 1):

No new object is allocated. `bigDecimal` refers to the same object as `BigDecimal.ONE`.

If you later do

```
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
```

a reference to another object (which has a value of 2) will be assigned to `bigDecimal`. After that statement `bigDecimal` and `BigDecimal.ONE` no longer point to the same object.

Comment: OK, but when you bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ONE); then bigDecimal is 2 (just tested with
    


    
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ONE;
    System.out.println(bigDecimal);
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
    System.out.println(bigDecimal);
output:
1
2

Answer (score 0):

From Java Documentation

> public static final BigDecimal ONE

The value 1, with a scale of 0.

Then **ONE is static and is the same instance object on the same classloader context**.